# "Read text messages to me" has stopped working

Tags: bluetooth, 7.5

Got a wireless headset a few months ago and discovered that it would read incoming SMS messages to me. It would neatly interrupt a podcast currently in progress, read the message, then go away again and resume playing the podcast. I didn't know it was going to do this but, hey, it was neat.

It suddenly stopped doing this a week ago. Now I'm finding I miss this feature.

I've restarted phone and headset. I've also made sure that in **Settings->Speech-> the "Play audio confirmations" option is set to **On** and "Read incoming text messages aloud" is set to **Bluetooth** (also tried changing this to **Bluetooth & headsets**).

This is WP7.5 on the Titan and a Plantronic M50. Although, none of that should matter much because it was working just fine until, as a I say, a week ago.

Comment: Are you able to do other voice commands from the headset? Like send a text message?

Comment: Nate, I've never tried!? How do I do that?

Comment: On most headsets there are three "action" buttons (at least ones I've had) Volume Up, Volume Down, and Contextual one, hangs up while in a call, etc. Try holding that button down, and see if it starts the voice command interface. On my wired headset it does the same thing as holding the Windows Logo button. Just trying to find out if the phone sees your device as a headset or not.

Comment: Any firmware updates to the phone recently?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to reset your phone. It's a bit cumbersome, but definitely works. I had the same problem a few days ago - Cortana stopped speaking while the rest of the phone was working normally. I wrote to [Windows Phone Central](http://www.wpcentral.com) and received this advice, which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Nokia Lumia phone and cortana stopped reading aloud my text messages
via bluetooth in my car.  The problem was that I had the volume turned off for applications on my phone.  When in car I got my wife to send me a text message when it came through I turned the volume up on my phone. everything fine now